# How to link menu to ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a menu built programmatically, I would like each menu item to link to different viewControllers in the storyboard, so I have control over the UI. So far I have:

```
import UIKit

class Setting: NSObject {

    let name: String
    let imageName: String

    init(name: String, imageName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.imageName = imageName

    }
}

class SettingsLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settings.count
    }

    let blackView = UIView()

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cv

    }()


    let cellId = "cellId"
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 40

    let settings: [Setting] = {

        return [Setting(name: "News", imageName: "news"), Setting(name: "Settings", imageName: "settings"), Setting(name: "UI list", imageName: "list"), Setting(name: "Book", imageName: "book"), Setting(name: "Me", imageName: "me"), Setting(name: "Cancel", imageName: "close")]

    }()

    func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }

    var TableViewController: TableViewController?


    func showSettings() {

        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)

            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)

            window.addSubview(collectionView)

            let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(settings.count) * cellHeight
            let y = window.frame.height - height
            collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, window.frame.width,height)

            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.blackView.alpha = 1

                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(0, y, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func handleDismiss() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }

        }
    }



    //func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //  return 3
    //}

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingCell

        let setting = settings[indexPath.item]
        cell.setting = setting

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width,height: cellHeight)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //print(setting.name)
        // handleDismiss()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { 

            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }

        }) { (completed: Bool) in

            let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
            if setting.name != "Cancel" {
                self.TableViewController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)

            }


        }


    }

    override init() {
        super.init()


        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self

        collectionView.register(SettingCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    }

}
```

So the menu list is taken from an array, which you can see from the code. I would like to link each one to its own viewController, I did follow an on-line tutorial for this and this menu system slides up from the bottom of the view to reveal itself.

Comment: Add your UI screen shot.

Comment: U mean of the menu? or which UI?

Comment: output of menu.

Comment: What part of this do you need help with? Zaid's answer shows how to respond to taps on a cell and fetch the selected Setting.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `collectionView(_didSelectItemAt :)` with following

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //print(setting.name)
        // handleDismiss()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: { 

            self.blackView.alpha = 0

            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = self.CGRectMake(0, window.frame.height, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)

            }

        }) { (completed: Bool) in

            let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
            if setting.name != "Cancel" {
                 goToNextViewController(setting: setting)

            }


        }


    }
```

And add following method

```
func goToNextViewController(setting: setting){
     if setting.name == "News"{
     //Here implement code to go to News screen
     }else if setting.name == "Settings"{
     //Here implement code to go to Settings screen
     }else if setting.name == "UI list"{
     //Here implement code to go to UIList screen
     }else if setting.name == "Book"{
     //Here implement code to go to Book screen
     }else if setting.name == "Me"{
     //Here implement code to go to Me screen
     }else{
      self.TableViewController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)
     }
}
```

If you are having showControllerForSetting method having already implemented logic for all other screens then only pass setting in `self.TableViewController?.showControllerForSetting(setting: setting)`

Comment: The goToNextViewController function implementation would be cleaner with a switch statement.

Comment: That is fine with if else too, making logic clear for him how he can reach the destination.

Comment: That looks like what I would need Zaid, can you show me some example code for the first screen where you have added comments.

Comment: Sure, it works, but a switch statement is more flexible, easier to read, and more efficient to execute. (A series of if/else if statements takes longer to match the last if than the first, since all previous if statements must be evaluated first. Granted, the performance difference is insignificant in this case.)

Comment: @DuncanC I agree with you, I was not doing that In XCode so found that easy to write.

Comment: @Sole For that I need to know how your view controller's are constructed, using `XIB` or `Storyboard` etc.
If storyboard how your segues are maintained, etc.

Comment: Just in storyboard Zaid, I am fairly new to IOS development

Comment: Share your storyboard then with all the view controllers are visible please.

Comment: Sole, you need to tell us how you are organizing your view controlllers. Are you using a navigation controller? Presenting modally?